# If line not present in the text file - python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a list with a set of strings and another dynamic list:

```
arr = ['sample1','sample2','sample3']
applist=[]
```

I am reading a text file line by line, and if a line starts with any of the strings in arr, then I append it to applist, as follows:

```
for line in open('test.txt').readlines():
    for word in arr:
        if line.startswith(word):
            applist.append(line)
```

Now, if I do not have a line with any of the strings in the arr list, then I want to append 'NULL' to applist instead. I tried:

```
for line in open('test.txt').readlines():
    for word in arr:
        if line.startswith(word):
            applist.append(line)
        elif word not in 'test.txt':
            applist.append('NULL')
```

But it obviously doesn't work (it inserts many unnecessary NULLs). How do I go about it? Also, there are other lines in the text file besides the three lines starting with the strings in arr. But I want to append only these three lines. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `elif word not in 'test.txt':` - `'test.txt'` here is just a string. Not a file, line from file or something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
for line in open('test.txt').readlines():
  found = False
  for word in arr:
    if line.startswith(word):
        applist.append(line)
        found = True
        break
  if not found: applist.append('NULL')
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that there are other lines in the text file other than the ones starting with the strings in arr. Your code inserts NULL for all the other lines too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
found1 = NULL
found2 = NULL
found3 = NULL
for line in open('test.txt').readlines():
  if line.startswith(arr[0]):
     found1 = line;
  elif line.startswith(arr[1]):
     found2 = line;
  elif line.startswith(arr[2]):
     found3 = line;
  for word in arr:

applist = [found1, found2, found3]
```

you could clean that up and make it better looking, but that should give you the logic you're going for.

Comment: still doesn't work :( The NULL is not getting appended in this case.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Do you always want a NULL appended?  Or do you want one null if any of the lines didn't match?

Comment: Consider that there is no line starting with 'sample2' in the text file. So what I want in the applist is, ['line starting with sample1','NULL','line starting with sample3']. There would be other lines in the text file, but I dont want to consider them, only these three lines.

Comment: That works, thanks! :) Thing is, I might have to add more strings to the arr list in the future, which might make things a little complex if I check for each value separately like how it is in your code. Any suggestions for making this easier?

Comment: sure, just make an array of "founds" that are all NULL, and use an array instead of those elif's